# Hit PHP from node server to process images

Tags: php, node.js, image-processing

I'm trying to hit a php page from a node server so that it will generate some thumbnail images. The problem is that it isn't generating the images when i hit do a jquery.get request from node. It works perfectly if I hit the page from a browser, though.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

$thumbsFolder = 'output/thumbs/';
$mediumFolder = 'output/medium/';

$originals = glob("output/*.jpg");
$thumbs = glob("output/thumbs/*.jpg");

// only process the images that are missing
$diff = array_diff($originals, $thumbs);
foreach ($diff as $file) {
  processImage($file, $thumbsFolder, 150);
  processImage($file, $mediumFolder, 600);
}

function processImage($imagePath, $outputFolder, $targetWidth){

  $imageSize = getimagesize($imagePath);
  $originalWidth = $imageSize[0];
  $originalHeight = $imageSize[1];
  $targetHeight = round($originalHeight * $targetWidth / $originalWidth);

  $urlElements = explode("/", $imagePath);
  $fileName = array_pop($urlElements);
  $fileName = explode(".", $fileName);
  $ext = array_pop($fileName);
  $newFilePath = $outputFolder.join($fileName, "").".".$ext;

  $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
  $sm = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
  imagealphablending($sm, false);
  imagecopyresampled($sm, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
  imagejpeg($sm, $newFilePath, 75);

}

?>
```

Here is the node script that hits the endpoint.

```
$.get("http://absolutepath.com/pi-lapse/thumb-gen.php", function(e){console.log(e)})
```

I also tried curl, and it didn't work.

Comment: Why not use [gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)?

Comment: That's a nice looking module, but I'm running these node servers on raspberry pi, so there's not much room to use more processing power. That's why I'm doing it on a remote apache server.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what "it didn't work" means for anyone to do anything.

Comment: The images don't generate. That's what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: Why are you trying to use jQuery from node?  You should probably use the native API, or something built on it like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

Comment: I tried using the native http module, but it gave me some strange error, so I switched to jquery to see if that would change things. Regardless, I just need to be able to hit the php script from node somehow.